# How to prevent image download from direct URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I am an ASP.Net Developer. As a part of Web Security module, I am instructed to prevent the image download from the application. How can I do that? Can anyone guide me on this?

```
<img id="lg-P002" onclick="processselection('P002');" src="assets/images/processes/ActiveImge/P002.jpg" alt="P002">
```

I am having an img tag with some image and
When I hover the mouse on the src attribute of the img tag, I could view the full URL of the image "http://localhost:10350/assets/images/processes/ActiveImge/P002.jpg"

This should be avoided. The Application users should not copy the full URL and download the source image.

How this can be avoided?

Comment: "This should be avoided. The Application users should not copy the full URL and download the source image" Why?

Comment: Application user should not access the images used in application through URL.

Comment: Yes, but why shouldn't they? Also, how is your application then going to access the image? While it's technically possible to download the image via JS and WebSockets, any technically savvy person can just copy your JS and do it themselves

Comment: If the web browser does download them because of normal usage, the user can get them whatever you do. What is usually done to make it harder is creating a file handler and registering it so to serve the file something is checked like Session data or refferer

Comment: What do you expect? At the moment the image is displayed, the user's browser already HAS downloaded the image.

Comment: Gist of above comments: You **can** make it _harder_ to download it. You **cannot** make it _impossible_. So, it's time to think about whether it is worth the hassle and whether the requirement makes sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

If this is just about hiding the URL of the image, not the content, one option is to [embed the image as a Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Example (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)):

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

This works well only for seldom used smaller images, because of the greater bandwidth usage for the page.

Interestingly, it's also possible to use this in CSS.

Comment: Upvoted because I think OP's main concern is that URL. OP: This still doesn't prevent a savvy person with the strong intent to get the image itself from getting it.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same solution in the first glance. Using an base64 encode image will hide the URL.